# A confusion about a proof of that $f(x_n) \to f(x)$ then $x_n \to x$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, continuity

In the book of *Topology* by Munkres, at page 130, it is given that

[image]

But I do not understand how can he concludes the converse result with the proof that he provided. I mean shouldn't we have chosen an arbitrary open set $U$ around $x$ and show that $\exists N $ s.t $\forall n \geq N$ 
$$x_n \in U \quad ?$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. The converse is this:

> Let $f\colon X\longrightarrow Y$. If $X$ is metrizable and if for every convergent sequence $x_n\to x$, the sequence $f(x_n)$ converges to $f(x)$, then $f$ is continuous.

So, now he is assuming that $f$ maps convergent sequences into convergent sequences. And he wants to prove that $f$ is continuous, which he does using the fact that the continuity of $f$ is equivalent to the assertion that, if $A\subset X$, then $f\bigl(\overline A\bigr)\subset\overline{f(A)}$.

Answer (score 2):

I assume there is a previous theorem that says something like

> A function $f:X\to Y$ is continuous iff, for every $A\subseteq X$ we have $f(\overline A)\subseteq \overline{f(A)}$.